# Can an unbounded series of functions converge pointwise to a bounded function?

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

I’m trying to find an example of a sequence of unbounded functions $f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which converge pointwise to a bounded function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.

I can find lots of examples of bounded sequences which converge pointwise to an unbounded function but can’t think of a function which converges unbounded $\rightarrow$ bounded.

Is this possible?

Comment: $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0, &x=0 \\ 1/x, & 0<x<1/n \\ 0, & x\geq 1/n\end{cases}$$

Comment: Did you consider $f_n=\frac f n$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but you will have to consider functions which are not continuous, since a continuous function is bounded on a compact set by Weierstrass' theorem.

Let $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an unbounded non-negative function.

For every $n\geq 0$, let $f_n = g \mathbb{1}_{g(x)> n}$.

Then for every $x\in [0,1]$, for every $k\geq g(x)$, we have $f_k(x) = g(x) * \mathbb{1}_{g(x)> k}(x) = 0$, so the sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ converges pointwise to the zero function.